# WindowsFormsHost is not visible when AllowsTransparency=“True” What are the risks of setting it to false?

Tags: c#, html, .net, wpf

In my WPF application I set the AllowsTransparency property to be false (`AllowsTransparency =“False”`).

The only thing that I have been notice is: when I set also `Background="Transparent"` ->  i will get black background (instead of Transparent Background.

What I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your exact question? why you wouldn't allow transparency?..

Comment: Because wpf WindowsFormsHost is not visible when AllowsTransparency=“True”. (before i starting with "workarounds")

Answer (score 1):

a tip: try to use inside a popup, so it works on separate layer, not a good solution but may help...

```
<Popup IsOpen="True" Placement="Relative" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=targetelement}">
<WindowsFormsHost x:Name="host" />
</Popup>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue:

[WPF and WinForms Interoperation Limitations:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522.aspx)

> WinForms controls cannot be displayed in WPF windows that have the
>   AllowsTransparency property set to true.